# Google Sheets - how to filter a range for rows that contain a substring in any column

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vtfRQRMTmH2JfZasDTwzVIeg4oDRKC_Qzb_Tz8i9TBE/edit#gid=0

Named Range: 'Registration' = A:F

Goal: H2 filters Column A for any row in Registration that contains the word "Yes".

I've tried looking into query() and filter() but those seem to require conditions by column(s). And I wasn't able to get lookup() to work either. And ideally I'd like the flexibility in case other columns are added or moved around.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome. Sorry but you probably shared the wrong sheet. There is no `Yes` in your data.

Comment: UPDATED to read "Yes" in the data.

Comment: UPDATED with example output in column J

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not pretty, but `QUERY` does work:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(
  Registration,
  "select A 
  where "&
    JOIN(" or ", CHAR(65+SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(INDEX(Registration,1,0))-1))&"='Yes'")
  )
)
```

Remarks:

- Index is interesting in that if you pass a 0 into either argument, it returns all rows or columns or both. I use this to count the number of columns excluding A in your named range.
- Then I sequentially generate A, B, C, etc. using the ASCII code. It only works up to Z, though, I'm afraid. If you need more, you can clone the table and reference it with `Col`+N and generate a sequence based on that.
- The query checks each of those columns per row for a "Yes".
- And you can add as many Columns or Rows as you like. Just don't forget to expand your Named Range as needed.

Comment: Thanks Calculuswhiz - this is really clever! The challenge here for me is that the named range "Registration" would ideally be pulling from a Google Form of students signing up for classes. So I would likely have more than 26 entries, and they'd be adding over time.